# Delete everything between two brackets in Vim, including newlines

Tags: vim, vi

Say I have the following python array literal:

```
def f():
    arr = [
        1,          
        2,
        3   
    ]
```

I want to delete everything in the brackets so that it becomes this:

```
def f():
    arr = []
```

How can I do that with minimal commands in vim?

---

These are some of my attempts:

- Using `di]` will delete the text, but not the empty newlines, leaving a lot of whitespace I'd have to delete:

  ```
  def f():
      arr = [         
      ]
  ```
- Using `da]` will delete the newlines, but also the brackets:

  ```
  def f():
      arr =
  ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
ca[[]<Esc>
```

or:

```
ca][]<Esc>
```

See `:help text-objects`.

Comment: Just doing ci[ worked better for me. Left the brackets.

Answer (score 7):

With your cursor on the first opening bracket (`[`), press `V`, followed by `%`. This will select the block which you then can join `J`, followed by `di[`.

Comment: Is it easy to do this a million times?

Answer (score 2):

Select the lines in visual mode (`v`) and use `J` to remove newlines. Then use `di[`.

Or if there are many lines, `di[` first, after which you move the cursor to top line and then `J`. This will potentially leave a space between the brackets which has to be removed with `x`.

Comment: That's pretty good. I can `va]` to select every line between the brackets, `J` to join then, then `di]` to delete the array contents. So `va]Jdi]` overall.

Comment: That's a neat way too do it too.

Answer (score 0):

I find using a code formatter shortcut saves a lot of time

If you install [vim prettier](https://github.com/prettier/vim-prettier), you could do `di[ <leader>p`

Using the formatter in JS for example means I don't have to remove extra spacing, jump to end of line to insert `;`, or fix indenting etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
:%s/\[\_.\{-}\]/[]/g
```

`\_.` to match any character including newline, and `\{-}` is the non-greedy command